# Does there exist a natural number $n$ such that all numbers $2n+1, 2n+3, 2n+5, ... , 2n+2015$ be nonprime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Does there exist a natural number $n$ such that all numbers

$2n+1, 2n+3, 2n+5, ... , 2n+2015$ be nonprime?

Can somebody help to solve this problem? I guess that it doesn't exist, but I have no idea how to start proving it.

Comment: To justify this duplicate: If you find 4031 consecutive prime numbers, the odd ones will satisfy this problem.

Comment: Sorry, ^ should be "4031 consecutive composite numbers", obvi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $
2n = 2017! + 2=k.
$
Since for each $k \geq 2$ it is well known that 
$$
k! + 2,k! + 3 \cdots ,k! + k
$$
are all composite, we have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  2017! + 3 = \left( {2017! + 2} \right) + 1 = 2n + 1 \hfill \\
  2017! + 5 = \left( {2017! + 2} \right) + 3 = 2n + 3 \hfill \\
  2017! + 7 = \left( {2017! + 2} \right) + 5 = 2n + 5 \hfill \\
   \vdots  \hfill \\
  2017! + 2017 = \left( {2017! + 2} \right) + 2015 = 2n + 2015 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
are all composite.